# Looking Up a CELL w/ 2 criteria (without VBA or ARRAY FORMULA)

Tags: arrays, excel

I need a excel formula which first matches the argument "Serial" in the data table then "Seq" then output the respective matching "Object"

Below is the data table.

```
Serial      Status Seq  Object
040846/Z/96/C   T   1   MOU
040846/Z/96/C   T   2   RAT
042190/Z/96/F   T   1   RAB
042368/Z/97/B   T   1   HAM
042368/Z/97/B   T   2   MOU
042368/Z/97/B   T   3   RAT
047608/Z/96/B   T   1   MOU
047675/Z/96/D   T   1   AMF
047675/Z/96/D   T   2   MOU
047675/Z/96/D   T   3   RAB
047677/Z/96/B   T   1   MOU
050573/Z/97/A   T   1   MOU
051077/Z/97/A   T   1   AMF
051077/Z/97/A   T   2   MOU
051077/Z/97/A   T   3   RAT
051077/Z/97/A   T   4   SEA
051080/B/97/A   T   1   MOU
051080/B/97/A   T   2   RAT
051080/Z/97/C   T   1   MOU
051080/Z/97/C   T   2   RAT
051087/Z/97/B   T   1   MOU
051091/Z/97/B   T   1   RAB
051091/Z/97/B   T   2   SHE
```

Concatenating the fields isn't feasible as database is too large.

The popular solution 
    =INDEX(C1:C20,MATCH(1,(A1:A20=D1)*(B1:B20=E1),0))

array formulae does work when I press CTRL+Shift+Enter however I'm unable to then substitute this into a 
    IF(a1="BLAH", (FORMULA), "DO NOTHING").

Of course if there is a way to insert this into IF THEN ELSE statement, that will be a valid answer.

Comment: You're saying you can't wrap an `If()` statement around the Index/Match array formula?

Comment: Yeah doesn't work for me. I tried putting {} around the whole statement, also didn't work. When i put the array formula in it's own cell, works fine. ?!?

Comment: You'll add the `{}` by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, not manually.  What are you trying to return out of your formula? Where will your formula go? (I am assuming your data that you posted is in columns A:D?

Comment: Basically I went the formula to match criteria 1 & criteria 2, and out the resultant cell.  This formula in order to function properly must be placed inside a IF() statement, which doesn't seem to be working.  YES the data above is an small section from the set.

Comment: Just to make sure, when you put it in the `If()` statement, still hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.  Also, here's another way to use Index/Match to find multiple criteria: `=Index(C1:C20,match([match1cell]**&**[match2cell],[match1range]**&**[match2range],0))`.  Where 'match cell` is the cell you want to match, and the matchRange is the range to find those matches.  (Enter as an array)